# SQL maxium innodb size issue

Tags: database, file, text, size

I am installing smtp extension suddenly I am facing with below Mysql error message

https://prnt.sc/127cedv

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs`

innodb_strict_mode = 0
innodb_log_file_size=100M

Hope you help

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name_involved; for analysis.